# Expand part of a preprocessor token

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The **C** preprocessor splits up source text into tokens and only does expansions matching those tokens. Usually this is the expected behavior, but sometimes not.

Take this example, I'd like to implement some template-like functionality in a nice way. Normally it's implemented like this:

```
#define add_function_template(mytype) \
    mytype add_##mytype(mytype a, mytype b) { \
        return a + b; \
    }
```

The concatenation operator `##` makes this expand, but having to quote the whole function with backslashes is very cumbersome. Is it somehow possible to do similar expansion for the function name outside a macro body?

E.g. something like

```
#define TYPENAME int
TYPENAME add_TYPENAME(TYPENAME a, TYPENAME b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The identifier `add_TYPENAME` is not expanded, the rest is. No how can I expand identifiers such as this? Helper macros would be OK too, but I can't find any sane way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with the C Preprocessor.  Preprocessing tokens (like `add_TYPENAME`) can't be split.  The simplest "solution" is a bit ugly:

```
#define CONCAT_IMPL(x, y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCAT_IMPL(x, y)
#define MAKE_TYPENAME_FUNCTION_NAME(x) CONCAT(x, TYPENAME)

TYPENAME MAKE_TYPENAME_FUNCTION_NAME(add_)(TYPENAME a, TYPENAME b) {
```

---

> having to quote the whole function with backslashes is very cumbersome

It may be cumbersome, but it's the cost of using the preprocessor for anything nontrivial.

Comment: This is definitely a bit ugly, but if preprocessor compatibility is good, I think it's usable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. Think on how it would screw up one's code.

`#define p f`

printf() would expand as frintf()

or `#define . ,`

and so on...

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's why I was pointing out using helper macros for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want, if you're willing to #include a .c file from another .c file.

Here is an example of how you would do it:

In **add_function_template.c:**

```
#define add_function(t) t add_##t(t a, t b)  // This line could be moved elsewhere.
add_function(mytype)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

In **footype.c:**

```
#define mytype footype
#include <add_function_template.c>
```